# How to apply aggregate and updateMany

Tags: mongodb

How can I apply this aggregate in updateAll?

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "payments",
      localField: "paymentId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "payment"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$payment",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      pricingOptionId: "$payment.pricingOptionId",
      quantity: "$payment.quantity"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      payment: 0 // Exclude the payment field if not needed
    }
  }
])
```

The original question was here, `aggregate` applies the right changes, but it has to be write back to the DB. How?

[MongoDB Aggregation: Joining Collections and Assigning Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78214379/mongodb-aggregation-joining-collections-and-assigning-fields?noredirect=1#comment137889254_78214379)

Comment: Just add a [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Would you add as an answer?

Comment: If your mongDB is 4.2 or later you can use `$merge`

Answer (score 0):

Since your pipeline applies to *all* documents in your collection, add an [`$out`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage which will overwrite the existing collection with all the docs generated by your aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.tickets.aggregate([
  // all your existing stages here,
  {
    $out: "tickets"
  }
])
```

And if it was only updating *some* documents which you wanted to write back and leave the others as is, then you can use [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)

```js
db.tickets.aggregate([
  // all your existing stages here,
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "tickets",
      on: "_id",
      whenMatched: "replace",
      whenNotMatched: "discard"
    }
  }
])
```

And the merge option would work even in the case of updating *all documents* instead of just some. But in that case, `$out` performs better since it doesn't need to check for existing docs, ids or do any actual "merging". And having `whenMatched: "replace"` also saves compute/comparison time.